# How to convert actionscript 2 code to actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2

I have to change logo in a flash document but its in actionscript 2 code so it gives error. When I try yo save the document The actionscript 2 code is below. Is there an easy way to convert to code in actionscript 3.
 How can I convert it to action script?

```
function buildMenu(success)
{
if(success)
{
  folder = this.firstChild.childNodes;
  var i;
  i = 0;
  while(i < folder.length)
  {
     var _loc4_ = mainMenu.attachMovie("mainBtn","mainBtn" + i,i + 500);
     var _loc7_ = menu_numbers.attachMovie("number","number" + i,i + 550);
     _loc4_.btnName.text = folder[i].attributes.NAME;
     MenuColor0 = new Color(mainMenu.mainBtn0.bg);
     MenuColor0.setRGB(10802437);
     MenuColor1 = new Color(mainMenu.mainBtn1.bg);
     MenuColor1.setRGB(8633375);
     MenuColor2 = new Color(mainMenu.mainBtn2.bg);
     MenuColor2.setRGB(5612349);
     MenuColor3 = new Color(mainMenu.mainBtn3.bg);
     MenuColor3.setRGB(1208203);
     MenuColor3._width = 20;
     var _loc9_ = menu_numbers.attachMovie("mask","numara_mask" + i,i + 
650);
     _loc9_._width = 60;
     _loc9_._height = 45;
     _loc9_._x = _loc9_._x + (menu_numbers["numara_mask" + (i - 1)]._x + 
menu_numbers["numara_mask" + (i - 1)]._width + btnSpacing + 65);
     _loc9_._y = 15;
     _loc7_.setMask(_loc9_);
     var _loc10_ = new Color(_loc7_);
     _loc10_.setRGB(16777215);
     _loc7_._alpha = 40;
     _loc4_.link = folder[i].attributes.LINK;
     _loc4_.subMenu = folder[i].childNodes.length;
     _loc4_._x = _loc4_._x + (mainMenu["mainBtn" + (i - 1)]._x + 
mainMenu["mainBtn" + (i - 1)]._width + btnSpacing);
     trace(_loc4_._width);
     _loc7_.numara.text = i + 1;
     _loc7_._x = _loc7_._x + (menu_numbers["number" + (i - 1)]._x + 
menu_numbers["number" + (i - 1)]._width + btnSpacing + 77);
     if(_loc7_ == menu_numbers.number1)
     {
        menu_numbers.number1._x = menu_numbers.number1._x + -4;
     }
     if(_loc7_ == menu_numbers.number2)
     {
        menu_numbers.number2._x = menu_numbers.number2._x + 8;
     }
     if(_loc7_ == menu_numbers.number3)
     {
        menu_numbers.number3._x = menu_numbers.number3._x + 10;
     }
     if(_loc4_.subMenu)
     {
        _loc4_.subfolder = folder[i].childNodes;
        _loc4_.createSubMenu = function()
        {
           if(switcher == false)
           {
              var _loc5_ = mainMenu.createEmptyMovieClip("subMenu",i);
              slide(mainMenu.subMenu2,mainMenu.subMenu2._y,- 
mainMenu.subMenu2._height - 
50,slideOutSpeed,"_y",mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeOut);
              switcher = true;
           }
           else
           {
              _loc5_ = mainMenu.createEmptyMovieClip("subMenu2",i + 200);
              slide(mainMenu.subMenu,mainMenu.subMenu._y,- 
mainMenu.subMenu._height - 
50,slideOutSpeed,"_y",mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeOut);
              switcher = false;
           }
           currSub = _loc5_;
           var _loc2_ = undefined;
           _loc2_ = 0;
           while(_loc2_ < this.subMenu)
           {
              var _loc4_ = _loc5_.attachMovie("subBtn","subBtn" + 
_loc2_,_loc2_ + 9000);
              _loc4_.btnName.text = this.subfolder[_loc2_].attributes.NAME;
              _loc4_.link = this.subfolder[_loc2_].attributes.LINK;
              var _loc3_ = new Color(_loc4_.bg);
              if(activeMain == mainMenu.mainBtn0)
              {
                 _loc3_.setRGB(10867973);
              }
              else if(activeMain == mainMenu.mainBtn1)
              {
                 _loc3_.setRGB(8699168);
              }
              else if(activeMain == mainMenu.mainBtn2)
              {
                 _loc3_.setRGB(5678142);
              }
              else if(activeMain == mainMenu.mainBtn3)
              {
                 _loc3_.setRGB(1273996);
              }
              _loc4_._x = activeMain._x;
              _loc4_._y = _loc4_._height + vSpace * _loc2_;
              _loc4_.onRelease = function()
              {
                 getURL(this.link,"");
              };
              _loc4_.onRollOver = function()
              {
                 var _loc2_ = new Color(this.bg);
                 _loc2_.setRGB(subActiveBg);
              };
              _loc4_.onRollOut = function()
              {
                 var _loc2_ = new Color(this.bg);
                 if(activeMain == mainMenu.mainBtn0)
                 {
                    _loc2_.setRGB(10867973);
                 }
                 else if(activeMain == mainMenu.mainBtn1)
                 {
                    _loc2_.setRGB(8699168);
                 }
                 else if(activeMain == mainMenu.mainBtn2)
                 {
                    _loc2_.setRGB(5678142);
                 }
                 else if(activeMain == mainMenu.mainBtn3)
                 {
                    _loc2_.setRGB(1273996);
                 }
              };
              _loc2_ = _loc2_ + 1;
           }

slide(_loc5_,-50,0,slideInSpeed,"_y",mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeOut);
           var _loc6_ = scope.attachMovie("mask","hitZone",1);
           _loc6_._x = mainX + currButton._x - 50;
           _loc6_._y = currButton._y - 5;
           _loc6_._width = _loc5_._width + 100;
           _loc6_._height = _loc5_._height + vSpace + mainY + 100;
           _loc6_._alpha = 0;
           _loc6_.useHandCursor = false;
           _loc6_.onRollOver = function()
           {
              closeMenu();
              callJS("0");
           };
        };
        _loc4_.onRollOver = function()
        {
           if(activeMain != this)
           {
              activeMain = this;
              activeStates(this.btnName);
              if(_root.link != a)
              {
                 LineBarColor = new Color(_root.LineBar);
                 if(activeMain == mainMenu.mainBtn0)
                 {
                    LineBarColor.setRGB(10802437);
                 }
                 else if(activeMain == mainMenu.mainBtn1)
                 {
                    LineBarColor.setRGB(8633375);
                 }
                 else if(activeMain == mainMenu.mainBtn2)
                 {
                    LineBarColor.setRGB(5612349);
                 }
                 else if(activeMain == mainMenu.mainBtn3)
                 {
                    LineBarColor.setRGB(1208203);
                 }
              }
              callJS("1");
              currButton = this;
              this.createSubMenu();
           }
        };
     }
     else
     {
        _loc4_.onRollOver = function()
        {
           if(activeMain != this)
           {
              activeMain = this;
              activeStates(this.btnName);
              closeMenu();
              currButton = this;
              if(_root.link != a)
              {
                 LineBarColor = new Color(_root.LineBar);
                 if(activeMain == mainMenu.mainBtn0)
                 {
                    LineBarColor.setRGB(10802437);
                 }
                 else if(activeMain == mainMenu.mainBtn1)
                 {
                    LineBarColor.setRGB(8633375);
                 }
                 else if(activeMain == mainMenu.mainBtn2)
                 {
                    LineBarColor.setRGB(5612349);
                 }
                 else if(activeMain == mainMenu.mainBtn3)
                 {
                    LineBarColor.setRGB(1208203);
                 }
              }
              callJS("1");
           }
        };
        _loc4_.onRollOut = function()
        {
           activeStates(null,null);
           activeMain = null;
           currButton = null;
        };
        _loc4_.onRelease = function()
        {
           if(activeMain != this)
           {
              if(_root.link != a)
              {
                 _root.link = a;
              }
              getURL(this.link,"");
           }
        };
     }
     i++;
  }
}
else
{
  trace("XML yükleme hatasi");
}
}
function closeMenu()
{
slide(currSub,currSub._y,- currSub._height - 
50,slideOutSpeed,"_y",mx.transitions.easing.Strong.easeOut);
 activeStates(null,null);
 activeMain = null;
 currButton = null;
}
function callJS(c)
{
var _loc1_ = undefined;
_loc1_ = String(ExternalInterface.call("ShowHideMenu",c));
}
function activeStates(txt)
{
txt.textColor = mainActiveText;
currButton.btnName.textColor = mainText;
}
function slide(who, startvalue, endvalue, y_speed, prop, ease)
{
slider = new 
mx.transitions.Tween(who,prop,ease,startvalue,endvalue,y_speed,true);
 }
var btnSpacing = 55;
var vSpace = 34;
var slideSpeed = 1;
var mainX = 230;
var mainY = 43;
var mainBg = 15461098;
var mainText = 16777215;
var mainActiveText = 16777215;
var slideInSpeed = 0.9;
var slideOutSpeed = 1.2;
var subMenuX = 250;
var subBg = 1208460;
var subActiveBg = 5810655;
a = 2;
var scope = this;
scope.createEmptyMovieClip("mainMenu",2);
mainMenu._x = mainX;
mainMenu._y = mainY;
var mask = mainMenu.attachMovie("mask","mask",100);
mask._width = scope._width;
mask._height = scope._width;
mask._y = 10;
mainMenu.setMask(mask);
var switcher = true;
var menuXml = new XML();
menuXml.ignoreWhite = true;
menuXml.onLoad = buildMenu;
menuXml.load(_root.MenuXmlPath);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [actionscript 2 to actionscript 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614293/actionscript-2-to-actionscript-3)

Answer (score 2):

There is no magic switch to convert AS2 to AS3.  If all you want to do is swap the logo, simply change your project to ActionScript 2.0 if you want to compile an AS2 project.

[image: Properties panel of the flash project]